# Split a string on multiple characters - Python

Tags: python

I have a string :

```
V51M229D180728T132714_ACCEPT_EC_NC
```

This needs to be split into

```
String 1 : V51 (Can be variable but always ends before M)
String 2 : M22 (Can be variable but always ends before D)
String 3 : D180728 (Date in YYMMDD format)
String 4 : 132714 (Timestamp in HHMMSS format)
String 5 : ACCEPT (Occurs between "_")
String 6 : EC (Occurs between "_")
String 7 : NC (Occurs between "_")
```

I am new to python and hoping to get some help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re` module:

```
import re
a = 'V51M229D180728T132714_ACCEPT_EC_NCM'
re.search('(\w+)(M\w+)(D\d+)(T\d+)_(\w+)_(\w+)_(\w+)', a).groups()
```

You will get:

```
('V51', 'M229', 'D180728', 'T132714', 'ACCEPT', 'EC', 'NCM')
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is of fixed pattern just sting slicing and list slicing works.

```
  aa = "V51M229D180728T132714_ACCEPT_EC_NC"                                          
  a = aa.split("_")                                                                 
  str1 = a[0][0:3]                                                                  
  str2 = a[0][3:6]                                                                  
  str3 = a[0][7:14]                                                                 
  str4 = a[0][15:21]                                                                
  str5 = a[1]                                                                       
  str6 = a[2]                                                                     
  str7 = a[3]                                
  print(str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7)
```

**Output**

V51 M22 D180728 132714 ACCEPT EC NC

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a regex with matching groups. See the `re` module.

For example,

```
>>> mystr = 'V51M229D180728T132714_ACCEPT_EC_NC'
>>> re.match('(.*?)(M.*?)(D.*?)T(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)', mystr).groups()
('V51', 'M229', 'D180728', '132714', 'ACCEPT', 'EC', 'NC')
```

In the pattern, the `()` indicate a group, and `.*?` will match the minimal number of characters to make the pattern fit.

Answer (score 0):

Use split(). From docs:

> str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
>
> Return a list of the words in the
>   string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at
>   most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at most
>   maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not specified or -1, then there
>   is no limit on the number of splits (all possible splits are made).

So you can use split('M', 1) to get the list of ['V51', '229D180728T132714_ACCEPT_EC_NC'], then split the second entry of the list with 'D' delimiter to get ['229', '180728T132714_ACCEPT_EC_NC']...

Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

As mxmt said, use regular expressions. Here is another equivalent regex, which might be a little easier to read:

```
import re

s = 'V51M229D180728T132714_ACCEPT_EC_NC'

pattern = re.compile(r'''
    ^        # beginning of string
    (V\w+)   # first pattern, starting with V
    (M\w+)   # second pattern, starting with M
    (D\d{6}) # third string pattern, six digits starting with D
    T(\d{6}) # time, six digits after T
    _(\w+)
    _(\w+)
    _(\w+)   # final three patterns
    $        # end of string
    ''', re.VERBOSE
)

re.match(pattern, s).groups() -> ('V51', 'M229', 'D180728', '132714', 'ACCEPT', 'EC', 'NC')
```